# Genus formula for a curve in a $2$-dimensional complex torus?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves

For a curve $C$ in a $2$-dimensional complex torus $T$, is there any formula to compute the genus of $C$? Say, in terms of self-intersection number?

For a curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ or a K3 surface, there is a genus formula in terms of the self-intersection number. I wonder if there is a similar formula for a $2$-dimensional complex torus.

Comment: There is a genus formula for a curve on any surface, that you'll find in any algebraic geometry book.

Comment: To expand on abx's comment, let me ask: what is the genus formula for curves in $\mathbf P^2$ or a $K3$ surface? In both cases it is an immediate application of the adjunction formula, which works for a curve on any surface.

Comment: have you found your answer?

Answer (score 4):

My answer will be for the case where both the curve $C$ and the surface $S$ are smooth (and connected), though I'm sure the result holds more generally.

---

Note that $\chi(C) = \langle e(TC), [C]\rangle$ where $e$ denotes the Euler class and $[C]$ is the fundamental class. As $C$ is (complex) one-dimensional, $e(TC) = c_1(TC)$. Note that we have an exact sequence of vector bundles $0 \to TC \to TS|_C \to NC \to 0$ where $NC$ is the normal bundle of $C$ in $S$. Therefore $c_1(TS|_C) = c_1(TC) + c_1(NC)$. By the adjunction formula, $NC = L(C)|_C$ where $L(C)$ is the line bundle associated to the divisor $C$. Rearranging, we see that

$$c_1(TC) = c_1(TS|_C) - c_1(L(C)|_C) = c_1(i^*TS) - c_1(i^*L(C)) = i^*c_1(TS) - i^*c_1(L(C))$$

where $i : C \hookrightarrow S$ is the inclusion. Therefore

\begin{align*}
\chi(C) &= \langle i^*(c_1(TS) - c_1(L(C))), [C]\rangle\\
&= \langle c_1(TS) - c_1(L(C)), i_*[C]\rangle\\ 
&= \langle c_1(TS) - c_1(L(C)), \gamma\cap[S]\rangle\\
&= \langle \gamma\cup(c_1(TS) - c_1(L(C))), [S]\rangle.
\end{align*}

where $\gamma$ is the Poincaré dual of $i_*[C]$. But the Poincaré dual of $i_*[C]$ is $c_1(L(C))$ so

$$\chi(C) = \langle c_1(L(C))\cup (c_1(TS) - c_1(L(C))), [S]\rangle.$$

As $\chi(C) = 2 - 2g(C)$, you can rearrange this equation to obtain a formula for the genus of $C$.

---

**Example:** If $S = \mathbb{CP}^2$ and $C$ is given by the zero set of $f(x, y, z) = x^4 + y^4 + z^4$. As $T\mathbb{CP}^2 = \mathcal{O}(3)$ and $L(C) = \mathcal{O}(4)$ we have $c_1(T\mathbb{CP}^2) = 3a$ and $c_1(L(C)) = 4a$ where $a = c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))$. Therefore we obtain

$$2 - 2g(C) = \langle 4a\cup(3a - 4a), [\mathbb{CP}^2]\rangle = \langle 4a\cup(-a), [\mathbb{CP}^2]\rangle = -4\langle a^2, [\mathbb{CP}^2]\rangle = -4.$$

So we can see that $C$ has genus $3$.

---

In terms of algebraic geometry, one may prefer to use the notion of intersection number in which case the formula becomes

$$2 - 2g(C) = -C\cdot K_S - C\cdot C$$

where $K_S$ is the canonical divisor associated to $\omega_S$, the canonical bundle.

If $S$ is a complex two-dimensional torus, then $K_S = 0$ so $2 - 2g(C) = - C\cdot C$ and hence $g(C) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}C\cdot C$. Note, this implies that $C\cdot C$ is even for every divisor in the torus.